# Trying to open Excel using ApachePOI with Serenity and Cucmber

Tags: apache-poi, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am getting the below error while trying to read the Excel. Using ApachePOI to open the excel workbook. Using Serenity with Cucumber framework and executing the command "mvn clean verify" to run the tests. Is it not possible to use ApachePOI without Main method? It works fine when I include this code in Main method.

```
    null
net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportGenerationFailedError: Failed to generate configuration report
        at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.waitForReportGenerationToFinish(ReportService.java:204)
        at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.generateReportsFor(ReportService.java:181)
        at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.generateReportsFor(ReportService.java:127)
        at io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporter.generateReports(SerenityReporter.java:937)
        at io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporter.handleTestRunFinished(SerenityReporter.java:323)
        at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:45)
        at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:9)
        at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberSerenityRunner$RunCucumber.evaluate(CucumberSerenityRunner.java:255)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.pc.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:405)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Collection;
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.waitForReportGenerationToFinish(ReportService.java:201)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Collection;
        at net.thucydides.core.files.TheDirectoryStructure.maxDepth(TheDirectoryStructure.java:58)
        at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.lambda$maxDirectoryDepthIn$2(FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:206)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$4$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:212)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1608)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.reduce(IntPipeline.java:496)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.max(IntPipeline.java:459)
        at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.maxDirectoryDepthIn(FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:207)
        at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.<init>(FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:129)
        at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.<init>(FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:78)
        at net.thucydides.core.requirements.FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.<init>(FileSystemRequirementsTagProvider.java:73)
        at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.service.CucumberTagProviderStrategy.getTagProviders(CucumberTagProviderStrategy.java:34)
        at net.thucydides.core.statistics.service.ClasspathTagProviderService.tagProvidersThatCanProcess(ClasspathTagProviderService.java:80)
        at net.thucydides.core.statistics.service.ClasspathTagProviderService.loadTagProvidersFromPath(ClasspathTagProviderService.java:56)
        at net.thucydides.core.statistics.service.ClasspathTagProviderService.tagProvidersFor(ClasspathTagProviderService.java:36)
        at net.thucydides.core.statistics.service.ClasspathTagProviderService.getTagProviders(ClasspathTagProviderService.java:28)
        at net.thucydides.core.model.TestOutcome.getTags(TestOutcome.java:1854)
        at net.thucydides.core.model.TestOutcome.addVersionsDefinedInTagsTo(TestOutcome.java:1734)
        at net.thucydides.core.model.TestOutcome.getVersions(TestOutcome.java:1729)
        at net.thucydides.core.model.TestOutcome.calculateDynamicFieldValues(TestOutcome.java:349)
        at net.thucydides.core.reports.json.gson.GsonJSONConverter.toJson(GsonJSONConverter.java:81)
        at net.thucydides.core.reports.json.JSONTestOutcomeReporter.generateReportFor(JSONTestOutcomeReporter.java:60)
        at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.generateReportFor(ReportService.java:239)
        at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.lambda$generateReportsFor$0(ReportService.java:177)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Remove your old copy of Apache Commons IO, and replace it with the one that ships with Apache POI?

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr, it worked after I changed the following dependency: <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I changed the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```